# How to store connection string to session in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core and I would like to access the **connection string** through the session but I am not sure at which point I should set the session value.

I can access connection string in `Startup.cs` but I think I cannot access `HttpContext` from there.

Here is the **Startup.cs** file

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            });

            // Here I can get connection string, but I cannot access Session
            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("devDb2");
            services.AddDbContext<attWebApiContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? It doesn't change.

Comment: I want to get connection string and use it inside application (Not necessarilly pass it through session)

Comment: But you created a DbContext with that connectionstring. What else do you need if you have already a DbContext to Inject in your classes?

Comment: I want to execute sql queries using SqlCommand and connection strings apart from using DbContext

Comment: Inject you context into a controller. and then just call context.Database  and you can run man sql commands from there

Comment: @kapantzak [Access Connection String inside an ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527344/access-connection-string-inside-an-asp-net-core-controller/47527773#47527773) has answer to your question

Comment: @kapantzak: That's not what session is for.

Comment: Thank you all, I know it's not best practice. I will follow @Set's recomendation