# How to add a "key" and its "name" to apsettings.js in ASP .NET Core Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, app-secret

In ASP .NET Core Web Applications I have noticed that the **connection string** can be put into **apsettings.jso**n or **secret.json** file as follows:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=the_key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

**secret.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=the_key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

And, it is used in the **startup.cs**.

```
public class startup
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnectionString")));
        }
}
```

## Problem:

In the same way the following is a how the *connection string* is passed in one of the controllers in the ASP .NET Core web Application:

**BlogUploadController.cs**

```
 AccountName = "MyAccount";
 AccountKey = "DGKC5745dfdG_+dkfkld";

 string UserConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=DGAKSECCDI654D_FGd;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", AccountName, AccountKey);
```

You can see that I have put the "connection string", and the "AccountKey" directly in the code (which is vulnarable for security threats). Can anybody how to put in the apsettings.json or Secret.json like I have put the database connection string in the above exmple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. but I could not find a way. Could you please help me. I am sorry to bother you. I am grateful if you can share a link of that at least.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Access Connection String inside an ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527344/access-connection-string-inside-an-asp-net-core-controller)

Comment: Also, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Thank you @RodrigoRodrigues for your support. I will read the article you shared.

Answer (score 3):

Adding things to the `appsettings.json` is a simple as editing the JSON. Take the custom `appsettings.json` below:

```json
{
    "Setup": "Setup Value",    
    "Config": {
        "Key": "My Key",
        "Token": "My Token"
    }
}
```

In order to get the custom values from the above, you can use the Configuration variable in the `setup.cs` file in APS.NET Core.

```cs
string setup = Configuration["Setup"];
```

To get a value such as `Config.Key`, you separate the names with a colon `:`, such as this:

```cs
string key = Configuration["Setup:Key"];
string token = Configuration["Setup:Token"];
```

Do be aware that using `appsettings.json` to hold secrets is a bad idea, as `appsettings.json` is usually a public document and not a secrets file.

Comment: Thnk you for your answer but I have a little concern. I just need one of my connection strings (`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=DGAKSECCDI654D_FGd;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`) to be put in apsettings.json. But I can see there are 02 in your answer as Setup & Config. So, for the the **key** I can put "UserConnectionString" & for the **token** I can put the above connections string. but for the **setup**, what should I put there?

Comment: An `appsettings` file is completely customizable. The first value in the json is the key, while the second is the value. Don't use the exact code I used, modify it to fit your needs. You want a pair like `cookie: "yum"` then make one. Its all up to how you configure the file.